# How to edit/ update dataGridView contents in UI and pass them to SQL workbench using C++ winforms?

Tags: c++, sql, datagridview

I have tried the following code, however, it's not working. Every time I hit the update button (button1), the UI shows as Data updated Successfully from the message box. That's why I am unable to understand whether SQL syntax is wrong or not. Any suggestions will therefore be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

            
    MySqlCommand^ cmdDataUpdate = gcnew MySqlCommand("update 'fmeafiless'.'fmeareadwrite' set 'Function/ Process', '"+dataGridView1->SelectedRows->ToString()+"';", conDataBase);
                
    try

    {

        fmeasda->UpdateCommand = cmdDataUpdate;

        MessageBox::Show("Data Updated Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception^ ex) {
        MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out... Though with a complex for loop, however its working!